# Can you void an individual document in an envelope in DocuSign?

Tags: docusignapi

If an envelope with multiple documents in has been sent out, can I void an individual document within the envelope or I have to void the whole envelope? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to void the whole envelope.

Or you could edit the envelope to delete or change one of its documents.

### Added

See [EnvelopeDocuments::delete](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/delete)

> **EnvelopeDocuments: delete**
>   Deletes one or more documents from an existing envelope that has not yet been completed.
>
> To delete a document, use only the relevant parts of the envelopeDefinition. For example, this request body specifies that you want to delete the document whose documentId is "1".
>
> {
>     "documents": [
>       {
>         "documentId": "1"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
>
> The envelope status must be one of:
>
> - created
> - sent
> - delivered

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you very much!

Comment: How do I delete one of its documents please?

Comment: I've looked at EnvelopesApi.DeleteDocuments. It looks like you can only delete documents from a draft envelope. Also it's deleting all. If the envelope is not draft and not completed either, How do you delete the specific document please?

Comment: Re-read the docs--see my updated answer. You can delete 1 doc if you want. If you have further questions, open a new question on StackOverflow.